# Crossfading between multiple images CSS

Tags: html, css

Im trying to do a crossfade between 3 images, using css.

Im new to @keyframes, so im having trouble to make it work.

Below, is the html and css code snippets:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="cf">
            <img class="bottom" src="assets/1.png" />
            <img class="top" src="assets/2.png" />
                <img class="bottom" src="assets/3.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#cf {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cf img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    92% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Right now, animation is acting weird, flashing from one image to another, at random animation times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close to the correct solution. `animation-direction: alternate;` causes the animation to "run backwards" once it reached 100%. With the odd times defined in your keyframe, this leads to uneven transitions:

```
keyframe        0% 17% 25%  92%   100%  92% 25% 17%  0% 17% ... infinite
state          :1   1   0    0     1     0   0   1   1   1
time in state  :   17%      62%    0%       62%         34%
transition time:        8%      8%       8%      8%
```

Simplify the keyframe to even times and you should be fine. With an even time distribution you don't even need the `animation-direction` at all. You can easily adjust the times by changing `animation-duration` of the keyframe and `animation-delay` for your images.

```css
#cf img {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
/* if you only want to cycle a finite amount of times, 
   simply change 'infinite' with # of iterations you need */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-direction: alternate; /* not strictly necessary */
    position:absolute;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(3) {
    /* add some delay for the first picture as well */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    /* distributing times evenly */
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/1" />
  <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/2" />
  <img class="bottom" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/3">
</div>
```

Strictly spoken, the first two transitions are marginally different since they transition to a picture of `opacity:1` instead of a fading picture and have slightly different times, but the difference is barely visible and imo not worth the effort compared to the resulting complication in code.

Comment: That worked! How to increase the time between img transitions? They are switching kinda fast.

Comment: Simply change the times - I added it to the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sometimes, background bellow images are showed. Can i make it stop?

Comment: how do you get it to loop once AND stay on the last image? it always seems to go back to the first. thanks! @Christoph

Comment: @bafromca It's not staying on the first image, it's an infinite loop (`animation-iteration-count: infinite;`). If you want a finite amount of iterations, simply change the iteration count, e.g. `animation-iteration-count: 4;`.

Comment: sorry, I was wondering if you knew how to get it to pause on the last frame I guess. I have an animation with an interation-count of 1, but it goes: slide 1, slide 2, slide 3, slide 1, even using `animation-fill-mode: forwards` @Christoph

Comment: How do you determine the keyframe percentages? For example, how to alter them if you want to have even more images in the animation?